# crosstab postgres - line to column

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, return-type

On my project, the data model changed and I have to do a new request to get information but in the past it looks like all data are in the same line, but now a part of that data are in an other table, and it returns me column.

So my request returns:

[image: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=724031request.jpg]

I thought it was easy but i don't really understand how the function `crosstab` works. I tried this:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT c.cd_type as typcou, c.dt_envoi as dtenvcou, c.commentaire as comment, c.signataire as signur
           FROM comm.courrier c
           WHERE c.id_formalite=1
     order by 1,2',
    'select lf.valeur as valeur from formalite.ligne_formalite lf, formalite.formalite f where lf.fk_formalite=f.id AND lf.fk_formalite=1'
     )

AS c(typcou text, dtenvcou text, comment text, signataire text, valeur1 text, valeur2 text, valeur3 text);
```

However, I got

> ERREUR: invalid return type
>   État SQL :42601
>   Détail :Query-specified return tuple has 7 columns but crosstab returns 5.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: What you want (based on given screenshot) is hardly possible : you can't match a specific value for a row to be a value for a new column (you ave no way to set the n-th value to the n-th column).

You shoud make a specific script to modify you table schema.

Comment: but when i go to the help of postgres, they say that you can use crosstab to do these 
http://docs.postgresqlfr.org/9.0/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

You failed to mention the column `formalite.libelle` in your question, which is essential for the solution.

I propose to use explicit `JOIN` syntax for your main query - generally easier to read and understand.

Since you have to spell out all columns in a column definition list anyway, it is more efficient to use a `VALUES` expression than `SELECT DISTINCT ...` for the second parameter of the `crosstab()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT c.cd_type, c.dt_envoi, c.commentaire, c.signataire
        , r.libelle, lf.valeur
   FROM   comm.courrier             c
   JOIN   formalite.formalite       f  ON f.id  = c.id_formalite
   JOIN   formalite.ligne_formalite lf ON lf.fk_formalite = f.id
   JOIN   norme.rubrique            r  ON r.id = lf.id_rubrique 
   WHERE  c.id_formalite = 1
   ORDER  BY 1'

   ,$$VALUES ('codepost'::text), ('bureau'), ('date')$$
   )
AS (typcou char, dtenvcou text, comment text, signur text
  , codepost text, bureau text, date text);
```

[**More explanation and links in this closely related answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

Aside: I wouldn't use `date` as column name ,it's a [reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860) in SQL and a type name in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! :

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT c.cd_type as typcou, c.dt_envoi as dtenvcou, c.commentaire as comment, c.signataire as signur, r.libelle, lf.valeur
       FROM comm.courrier c, formalite.ligne_formalite lf, formalite.formalite f, norme.rubrique r
       WHERE c.id_formalite=f.id AND lf.fk_formalite=f.id
       AND c.id_formalite=1 AND r.id = lf.id_rubrique ORDER BY 1',
       'SELECT DISTINCT libelle FROM norme.rubrique ORDER BY 1')
AS (typcou char, dtenvcou text, comment text, signur text, codepost text, bureau text, date text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some open source ETL studio in order of preference:

1. talend
2. pentaho
3. jaspersoft

especially if you will have to do this often for large data volumes, but I am wondering, should you really be using Postgresql? You can also use these tools to migrate from one database server to another, should you wish.